# Python Why Does This While Loop Control Work

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, break

So I was building a script and needed a conditional. I went with a variabled-while loop for control like so.

```
while a == True
```

While coding it I forgot the variable and ended up with this:

```
while True: ## Num hands control loop
    try:
        v_NumHands = int(raw_input("Enter number of hands desired, 1 - 7:"))
        if (v_NumHands < 1) or (v_NumHands > 7): ## Checks num of hands is in range
            print("Not correct, try again.")
        else: break 
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter a number.")
print("Hands: %s") %(v_NumHands)
```

I figured that it would not work as the 'break' should break out of the 'if' conditional, but not the 'while loop.' However it does work and I don't know why.

So why does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've discovered that `break` only breaks out of loops and not `if` conditionals :)

Here are the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: You are correct. I thought that 'break' got me out of all conditionals and loops. My bad. Thanks.

Comment: actually, just reading the docs myself, I didn't realize that `for` and `while` loops could have `else` statements so, thank you.

Comment: Me too. After I saw your answer, I double checked it and saw the same thing about 'else' in 'while' and 'for' loops. So I learned two things from one question. Thanks.